# Creating conditional statements for JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a very novice question, so apologies if the answer to this is obvious.

I am using JQuery to toggle the contents of items based on whether the item has been clicked. I have been able to successfully implement the toggle feature.

I now need to have it load with the first two items set to show() with the rest set to hide(). I have given a unique class name to these first 2 items. I know that I can simply do a `$('div.activeitem').show()` and then hide thee rest, but I'd prefer to setup a condition.

I am a JQuery novice, so I don't know how to target these elements or their classes in a conditional statement. I've searched google but have been unsuccessful. I want a conditional that asks if the div "newsinfo" also has the class "jopen" then show(), else hide().

Thanks for your help. I have attached my code to help you understand the context of my question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    // Here is where I'd like to implement a conditional
                    $('div.newsinfo').hide(); // this would be part of my else
                    $('h5.newstoggle').click(function() {
                        $(this).next('div').slideToggle(200);
                        return false;
                    });
                });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about simply

```
$('div.newsinfo').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('jopen')){
       $(this).show()
    }else{
       $(this).hide();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

there is `hasClass()` function. Better way is using toggleClass().

For example:

```
$('div.blocks').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('class_name');
});
```

after first click class will be added, after second - removed... and so on ^^

Answer (score 1):

JQuery has an .[hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) function.

i.e.

```
if($(".selectableItem").hasClass("selected")){
    //remove selection
    $(".selectableItem").removeClass("selected");
}else{
    //remove the selected class from the currently selected one
    $(".selectableItem .selected").removeClass("selected");
    //add it to this one
    $(".selectableItem").addClass("selected");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a default css to jopen class to `display: block` and the others to `display: none` ?

something like

```
 .newsinfo {display: none}
 .jopen {display:block!important}
```

Comment: it's not necessary use `!important` in this case couz .jopen notation goes later ;-)

Comment: True. I just added it to emphasize jopen should override newsinfo.

Answer (score 1):

Just use selectors.  For example, if all divs with the class "newsinfo" are visible by default:

`$("div.newsinfo:not(.jopen)").hide();`

If they're all hidden by default:

`$("div.newsinfo.jopen").show();`